# how to make site is public accessible without login

Tags: force.com-sites

i have created a site with inquiry form which will be place in some other websites. It will create a case. it goes to unauthorized page.

I have checked all the settings and made  login not allowed too.

any thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you add the page in public access settings? If you click on the site then on top you have a button where you can check public access settings, the page need to be added there also.

Second thing if you use fields that come from the Case object these need to be available also on the public access settings.

[image]

And third for this functionality did you check the web to case functionality from Salesforce? This pretty much does what you want, just out of the box. to setup web to case look here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm&language=en

Comment: Thanks Seven. I have missed some fileds to make visible in field level settings.